# How to use data separately in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, separator

I'm writing a program in Java that reads data from a text file into an Arraylist.
The text file has 10 lines of data and each line contains a piece of data in the format of: "Integer1-String1:String2" example: "123-ABC:DEFG".I would like to save Integer1, String1 and String2 like this:

```
int listNumber; //This would be Integer1
String listData1; //This would be String1
String listData2; //This would be String2
```

So my question is how can I do this without saving each type of data into separate array.
I was thinking about something like this but it's not working:

```
int givenNumber = Integer.parseInt(myArrayList.substring(0, "-"));
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
final String INPUT = "data.txt";
Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(INPUT));

ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

while (input.hasNext()){
                myArrayList.add(input.next());
            }

for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) {
                int givenNumber = Integer.parseInt(myArrayList.substring(0, "-"));
                System.out.println(myArrayList.get(i)); //Print the all data
            }
```

Sorry if this information is not clear but I'm new to Java and and don't know to describe it better.

Comment: So your question is how to store the 3 elements "together" but not using 3 ArrayList, is that right?

Comment: Scanner input was never used?

Comment: Yes, i want to store them together but read each data separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to create a helper class for your data:

```
class ListData {
   int listNumber;
   String listData1;
   String listData2;

   ListData(int listNumber, String listData1, String listData2) {
      this.listNumber = listNumber;
      this.listData1 = listData1;
      this.listData2 = listData2;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString(){
       return listNumber + "-" + listData1 + ":" + listData2;
   }
}
```

And then store it in a Array of ListData:

```
List<ListData> datalist = new ArrayList<>();
datalist.add(new ListData(listNumber, listData1, listData2);
```

**EDIT:**
Your implementation is not parsing the data from the scanner. The following snippet parses the [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) input line by line adding to the list.

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
   // Read each line from the scanner
   String input = input.next();

   // Split data on two delimiters '-' and ':'
   String[] data = input.split("-|:");
   int listNumber = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
   String listData1 = data[1];
   String listData2 = data[2];

   // Add to the datalist
   datalist.add(new ListData(listNumber, listData1, listData2));
}
```

Comment: I added a ´toString()´ method to make it easier to print the object

Comment: I get this syntax error " insert ")" to complete Expression" after:datalist.add(new ListData(listNumber, listData1, listData2);

Comment: As the error message suggests, I didn't place enough closing brackets. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

you can make an ArrayList of ArrayLists,2d array, and each Arraylist in that Arraylist can be set to a differet type. For example:

```
  ArrayList<ArrayList> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
  a.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
  a.add(new ArrayList<String>());
  a.add(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Class that stores all three values. Create the class in a new file named "LineEntry.java" in the same folder.

```
public class LineEntry{
    int listNumber; //This would be Integer1
    String listData1; //This would be String1
    String listData2; //This would be String2
    public LineEntry(String line){
         // You have to check wrong input cases as well.
         String [] token = line.split("-|:");  
         listNumber = Integer.parseInt(token[0]);

         listData1 = token[1];
         listData2 = token[2];
    } 
}
```

and create objects from this class when reading each line. Put the objects in an ArrayList

Comment: You need to add getters as well.